# Is there an easy way to launch the built-in Angular-slickgrid column picker menu from a button instead of right clicking

Tags: angular-slickgrid

Is there an easy way to launch the built-in Angular-slickgrid column picker menu from a button instead of right clicking?

I know how to change which columns are hidden/shown programmatically, but I don't want to make my own UI for selecting them, since the built-in one is great - I just want to be able to launch it from a button.

Comment: You can toggle the Grid Menu on the fly with `showGridMenu` but there's no such function in the Column Picker plugin, so you won't be able to do that currently. The only thing you can do, which I highly encourage, would be to contribute code to add a `showPicker` function to the [6pac/SlickGrid](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid) fork specifically in the [slick.columnpicker.js](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/blob/master/controls/slick.columnpicker.js) plugin. It shouldn't be too hard to create that function which can reference the picker element than call `$menu.show()` or `$menu.hide()`

Comment: Thank you. I looked at the fork page. Is there a page with information about the process for how to contribute code?

Comment: Contributing to any GitHub project is easy, clone the repo on your local, push your changes, create a pull request and make the branch to merge to 6pac/slickgrid. For more info, just google it, here's maybe a good youtube video to start https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=waEb2c9NDL8